# Unable to start new project generated by express-generator. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: express

### So I created a git repo -> npm init -> running express-generator getting this error

well it's something related to the sass I guess

```
$end:DEBUG='src:*'; npm start
ObjectNotFound: Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'end' does not exist.

> src@0.0.0 start
> node ./bin/www

internal/fs/utils.js:307
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\MegaMind\Projects\inventoryInExpress\src\node_modules\node-sass\vendor'
    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:1021:3)
    at Object.getInstalledBinaries (C:\Users\MegaMind\Projects\inventoryInExpress\src\node_modules\node-sass\lib\extensions.js:133:13)
    at foundBinariesList (C:\Users\MegaMind\Projects\inventoryInExpress\src\node_modules\node-sass\lib\errors.js:20:15)
    at foundBinaries (C:\Users\MegaMind\Projects\inventoryInExpress\src\node_modules\node-sass\lib\errors.js:15:5)
    at Object.module.exports.missingBinary (C:\Users\MegaMind\Projects\inventoryInExpress\src\node_modules\node-sass\lib\errors.js:45:5)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\MegaMind\Projects\inventoryInExpress\src\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MegaMind\Projects\inventoryInExpress\src\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\MegaMind\\Projects\\inventoryInExpress\\src\\node_modules\\node-sass\\vendor'
}
```